# Acessar indices de um array que esta dentro de outro array

Tags: php, array

Tenho o *array* abaixo e preciso criar uns `foreachs` para percorrer ele e pegar o produto e a qtd.

```
$array = array(
            array(
                'loja' => 'Loja1', array(
                    array(
                        'produto' => 'bolsa', 'qtd' => 1
                    ),
                    array(
                        'produto' => 'bolsa 3', 'qtd' => 3
                    )
                )
            ),
            array(
                'loja' => 'Loja2', array(
                    'produto' => 'bolsa 2', 'qtd' => 2
                )
            )
        );
```

Tentei dessa forma, mas ele não reconhece os índices:

```
foreach($array as $a){
     foreach($a as $produto){
           $p = $produto['produto_id'];
           $q = $produto['qtd'];
     }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eu mexeria um pouco na sua estrutura, assim:

```
$array = array(
    array(
        'loja' => 'Loja1', 
        'produtos' => array(
            array(
                'produto' => 'bolsa', 'qtd' => 1
            ),
            array(
                'produto' => 'bolsa 3', 'qtd' => 3
            )
        )
    ),
    array(
        'loja' => 'Loja2', 
        'produtos' => array(
            array(
                'produto' => 'bolsa 2', 'qtd' => 2
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Aí o loop seria:

```
foreach ($array as $loja) {
    foreach ($loja['produtos'] as $produto) {
        $p = $produto['produto'];
        $q = $produto['qtd']; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Ele não acessa os índices: Illegal string offset 'produto'.

Comment: A estrutura da segunda loja estava diferente da primeira (já no seu código original). Corrigi no meu.

Comment: https://ideone.com/oaNCvJ

Answer (score 4):

Amigo, isso esta parecendo atividade avaliativa de curso universitários... mas vamos ao que interessa, a estrutura `foreach` para percorrer esse Array **DESUNIFORME** seu é:

```
foreach ( $array as $loja ) {
    echo "<strong>Loja: {$loja['loja']} </strong><br>";

    $itens = $loja[0];
    if ( isset( $itens['produto'] ) ) {
        echo "-Item: {$itens['produto']} <br>";
        echo "-Qtd: {$itens['qtd']} <br><br>";
    } else {
        foreach ( $loja[0] as $key => $value ) {
            echo "-Item: {$value['produto']} <br>";
            echo "-Qtd: {$value['qtd']} <br><br>";
        }
    }
}
```

***Nota: Tomei a liberdade de incluir algumas tags HTML, para melhor exibição...***

O ideal é que você tenha uma estrutura uniforme nesse Array para armazenar os dados, percebe-se que há uma mistura de Arrays bidimensionais com índices numéricos e índices literais, isso da uma confusão na hora de você manipular esses dados, que você vai passar muita raiva quando isso tiver muitas linhas e colunas...

Mas como eu sei que nem sempre é possível fazer da forma que desejamos, se for possível você mudar a estrutura de alimentação desse Array vou deixar uma sugestão, veja que a leitura é mais simples também.

```
$array = array(
            array(
                'loja' => 'Loja1', 
                'itens' => array(
                    array(
                        'produto' => 'bolsa', 'qtd' => 1
                    ),
                    array(
                        'produto' => 'bolsa 3', 'qtd' => 3
                    )
                )
            ),
            array(
                'loja' => 'Loja2', 
                'itens' => array(
                    array(
                        'produto' => 'bolsa 2', 'qtd' => 2
                    )
                )
            )
        );

foreach ( $array as $loja ) {
    echo "<strong>Loja: {$loja['loja']} </strong><br>";

    foreach ( $loja['itens'] as $itens ) {
        echo "-Item: {$itens['produto']} <br>";
        echo "-Qtd: {$itens['qtd']} <br><br>";
    }
}
```

Nesse formato, a hierarquia fica um pouco mais padronizada e simples.